# How to include the bootstrap framework in netbeans web application project?

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, netbeans

I have a java web application project in netbeans. I would like to know how to include the bootstrap framework in this project. It is important that the project works without using Internet access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just download the Bootstrap file from [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com) and unzip it into your assets folder. Where this folder is depends on the structure of the framework you are using or even if you are using some framework. Then just add Bootstrap CSS and Javascript files to your pages. Then again, the correct way to do this depends on the framework you are using. If you are using JSF2, for instance, add these files to your template(s) and they will load when needed.